# How to programmatically ingest PNG images into ArcGIS server for tile layer display

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have recently started to familiarize with ArcGIS. Reading tile layers seems pretty straight forward. However, I would like to ingest my own PNG imagery files and read them through a web service call programmatically using either Java or Python. I have not been able to find a straight solution.

I have a system that generates PNG images. I would like to programmatically call the ArcGIS server web service API to ingest the PNG images into a layer as tiles and at the same time add the tiles to a cache. Which API/service call will support this operation? I will appreciate either a high level explanation of steps or a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a python script published as a geoprocessing service and use the REST API to call the images from your web application.

1. Place your tiles folder somewhere ArcGIS Server have access
2. Create a toolbox using a python script with parameters: string input
   and file output (derived)
3. Program a python script that will take the string input such
   "/0/0/0.png" etc... (`arcpy.getParameter`) and parse it  to go take the correct images in the correct folder, and serve it as output (`arcpy.SetParameter`)
4. In your map api use the the geoprocessing service url such
   http://www.myArcgisServer.com/rest/services/myTilesServer?{x}/{y}/{z}.png to call the tiles as needed

Answer (score 0):

Well if the png imagery are georeferenced then you could create a rasterdataset from them and create a ImageService. For more details on how to create Image service please look at the below link.
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/windows/key-concepts-for-image-services.htm